# Can one word form a phrase?

Tags: grammar, phrases

Can one word form a phrase?

For example:

> **Man is mortal**.

There is no modifier. So, here is there any **phrase**?

Comment: Of course, that's a verb phrase! But it's also three words, so it's not so clear what you're asking

Comment: @curiousdannii OP is clearly talking about the subject *man*, not the whole clause. The clue is in the title!

Comment: @Araucaria-him No, that's not clear. Please don't make edits that change posts substantially. You're not a mind reader!

Comment: @curiousdannii It very clearly says in the title  **"Can one word form a phrase"**. How can your comment ""it's three words" apply to OP's concern?

Comment: Hi Salim, could you confirm which word you are thinking about in particular?

Comment: The answer varies depending on the approach. In school grammar, the answer is "no". A single word is just a word, not a phrase; in order to have a phrase, you need to have two or more words. In contrast, the answer is "yes" in many university syntax courses, where a more articulated understanding of sentence structure is put forward. Personally, I prefer the school grammar approach, but my stance is a minority position among syntacticians.

Comment: @Araucaria-him See that the subject **man** is formed with a single noun. Is it a phrase or just a noun? Similarly, look at the predicator 'is' and complement 'mortal'. Those are also single functions. So, can these single functions be phrases?

Comment: @Tim What is ‘school grammar’ exactly? If you mean just ‘the kind of grammar taught in (primary/secondary) school’, then that is a restriction I never came across in my time at school. To the extent that we ever learnt about the concept of a ‘phrase’ as a syntactic constituent at all, we were certainly never taught that they have to be multi-word. Would your definition then mean that “People cheat – ignore them” contains no phrases at all? That’s definitely not what we were taught as kids.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet. The definition of "phrase" in the Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar is "a linguistic unit at a level between the word and the clause". That definition excludes individual words from qualifying as phrases. A similar definition can be found in the New Oxford Dictionary of English: "a small group of words standing together as a conceptual unit, typically forming a component of the clause". Again, a phrase consists of more than one word according to this definition. These definitions are consistent with what I learned in my school days long before I became a grammarian.

Comment: @Tim I disagree that the ODEG definition excludes individual words. It says phrases are units at a **level** between the word and the clause, not at a _length_ between the word and the clause. The fact that phrases are at a higher syntactic level than individual words does not mean that an individual word can’t make up a phrase – that’s the basic concept of a phrase. The NODE definition is entirely useless; it would exclude very long phrases (not a ‘small’ group of words), but include completely unrelated adjacent words (only ‘typically’ forming a component of the clause).

Comment: @TimOsborne You know it's funny about these attempts to make the word phrase into something it isn't. The CGEL crowd (and maybe others?) like to say that individual nouns are phrases and I JUST do not get it. What's the point of that? If you say a word such as a noun is a phrase, and they are equivalent, why bother with two words? Yes, a phrase is more than one word.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet. Your interpretation of the first definition I gave is debatable, and you have ignored the second definition.  Interestingly, I have just found the following definition of "phrase" in Fromkin's volume Linguistics (p. 708), "phrase: a sequence of adjacent words that form a syntactic unit or constituent (a component part) in the structure of a sentence". That definition also appears to exclude individual words from counting as phrases.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet. Check out the definition here in the online Cambridge Dictionary: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/phrase. You can find there that a phrase is defined as "a group of words that is part of, rather than the whole of, a sentence". That definition also excludes individual words from counting as phrases.

Comment: @Tim Yes, my interpretation is debatable; so is yours. Which second definition did I ignore? The Camridge definition seems adequate to me, apart from limiting phrases to being multi-word entities, but Fromkin’s definition completely needlessly confuses things by bringing adjacency into the picture (excluding phrases with inserted words from being phrases, for example).

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet. You ignored the second definition I provided in my original comment containing definitions. I cited two dictionaries, the Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar and the New Oxford Dictionary of English. You ignored the latter definition, which also supports the OP's question.

Comment: @Tim No, I didn’t. I wrote, “The NODE definition is entirely useless; it would exclude very long phrases (not a ‘small’ group of words), but include completely unrelated adjacent words (only ‘typically’ forming a component of the clause)”. The fact that it excludes single words is the least of the problems with that definition.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet. I see. I misread your use of "NODE", thinking you meant "node", which made your answer difficult to understand.

Comment: Fromkin’s and Cambridge are of course entirely fine if you accept “sequences” and “groups” of one element. This is a very common understanding of these words in technical definitions.

Comment: In my school days, the phrase level was largely implicit. On questions like “What is the subject in this sentence?” we were supposed to answer with a full phrase. We never complained when the subject only consisted of one word…

Answer (score 3):

In Generative Syntax, specifically "X-bar theory", a phrase is (or was) defined as the "maximal projection" of a category feature. The idea is that a word which takes a complement or a modifier covers the whole unit with its category feature because they behave as a group. That's why "the old **man** in the grey coat" is called a noun phrase, just like "the man". Whatever the size of this nominal group, it can function as the subject of a clause, in combination with a verb and hence, a VP. As a consequence, a single word (like "people") is also a phrase, because its category feature, N, simply does not extend any farther. A single word can be "maximal" if no further projection of the category feature occurs before it is used as a complement of some other head. In this theory, any item that functions as a complement or a modifier, must be considered a phrase, no matter how big or small it is.

Theories of grammar differ, however, in the extent to which they rely on the notion of a phrase. So you might get other answers in other theories.

(Sorry for not providing literature in English; the above is found in German in https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrase_(Linguistik)#Phrasen_tragen_Kategoriemerkmale but the references there are all German textbooks).

Comment: The answer to the OP's question is simply, yes: a phrase can consist of a single word, i.e. just a head. We don't need generative grammar or X-bar theory to tell us that.

Comment: I have seen people from dependency grammar answering "no" to the same question. So it seems to be theory-dependent.

Comment: @BillJ What Alazon said above. For evidence see Tim Osborne (dependency grammarian)'s comment under the Q.

Comment: @Araucaria-him? I'm agreeing with Alazon, but saying that we don't need to invoke arcane theoretical concepts and formalisms to establish an answer to the OP's very simple question.

Comment: Every answer should be based on some foundation, don't you think? "Phrase" is a theoretical concept, so any answer will presuppose some theory, even if it happens to be a naive theory...

Answer (score -5):

"Socrates is mortal" and "Man is mortal" are standard examples in introductions to classical logic. There is hardly any doubt that these form valid propositions.

The unusual syntax ("So, here is there") and, let's say, this being the internet where foreign speakers are in the majority, it seems very liky that OP is not a native speaker and that they have a different itch to scratch, in case of a GTP bot not a speaker of any language most likely.

Therefore it is nonsense to bicker about the definition of "phrase".

Comment: Huh? How does that answer contribute in any meaningful way? The OP question is good because it is drawing attention to a disconnect in how the term phrase is understood inside and outside of linguistics.

Comment: The OP is not in any meaningful way drawing attention to the defintion of "phrase" as a phrase, as a word, or anything, outside the quoted example of "Man is mortal".

Comment: I understood the OP's question immediately. I think most people who have studied syntax will do so. They recognize that how a layperson understands and uses the term "phrase" is different form how most grammarians use the term.

Comment: The question is immediately understandable. This answer – or at least its relation to the question – is not understandable in any way.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet you have also argued that "The fact that phrases are at a higher syntactic level than individual words" (above in comments) so it's immediately clear why you can't understand this answer.